# How can I remove the first and last Node from doubly linked list?

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list

I have a homework to write a method that will remove the FIRST Node and return its value in a doubly linked list in O(1), and one more method to remove the LAST Node in doubly linked list and return its value in O(1). This is what I did so far.

```
class DoubleList<T>
{
    DNode _start;
    DNode _end;

    public void AddFirst(T value)
    {
        DNode tmp = new DNode(value);
        tmp._next = _start;
        tmp._prev = null;
        if (_start != null)
        {
            _start._prev = tmp;
        }
        _start = tmp;
        if (_start._next == null)
            _end = tmp;
    }

    public void AddLast(DoubleList<T> doubleyList, T value)
    {
        DNode tmp = new DNode(value);
        if (_start == null)
        {
            AddFirst(value);
            return;
        }
        DNode lastNode = GetLastNode(doubleyList);
        lastNode._next = tmp;
        tmp._prev = lastNode;
        _end._next = tmp;
        _end = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this over 40 years ago in college.   The only really way of learning is to take a piece of paper and solve on paper before trying in code.  Draw a picture of three nodes connected by 6 links and the first node pointing to null.  Remember you can have one node. two nodes, or three or more nodes in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution I came out with, trying to use your syntax:

```
public DNode RemoveHead()
{
    // "Save" the current head to return it at the end
    DNode head = _start;

    if (_start != null)
    {
        // The start becomes the element next to the current one
        _start = _start._next;

        // The first node has to have no "previous" one
        if (_start != null) _start._prev = null;
    }

    return head;
}

public DNode RemoveTail()
{
    // "Save" the current tail to return it at the end
    DNode tail = _end;

    if (_end != null)
    {
        // The end becomes the element previous to the current one
        _end = _end._prev;

        // The last node has to have no "next" one
        if (_end != null) _end._next = null;
    }

    return tail;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a class doubleList in C# that have these methods.

Check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: i know, but my home work is to write these methods by myself..To study the structure of the data..

Answer (score 0):

Further more from the solution provided above, I would suggest that you alter the size of the doubly linked list as well so that you're more space complexity conscious as well as time complexity conscious. You can find my solution below that removes the first or the last node in a list as well as adjusting the count.

```
public void RemoveFirst()
        {
            if (Head == null && Tail == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

            Head = Head.Next;
            Head.Previous = null;
            Count--;
        }

public void RemoveLast()
        {
            if (Head == null && Tail == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

            Tail = Tail.Previous;
            Tail.Next = null;
            Count--;
        }
```